# Find detailed git log after certain commit

Tags: git, gitlab

For grading purposes, I want to find the metric of how many lines any author committed after a certain commit. I looked at git log but there is just too much data for it to be reasonably counted. Is there another method to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git log` to see what files have changed and how many lines of them:

```sh
git log --author="aerabi" --pretty=tformat: --numstat
```

The output would look like this:

```
10      67      tsconfig.json
2       2       package-lock.json
1       1       package.json
25      0       README.md
```

First column for added and the second for removed.

And because it's a simple `git log`, you can limit the commits in many different ways:

**Last 5 commits**

```sh
git log --author="aerabi" --pretty=tformat: --numstat -n4
```

**One certain days**

```sh
git log --author="aerabi" --pretty=tformat: --numstat --before=2022-01-13 --after=2021-07-12
```